# Which API method provides the drawing of a city's boundaries?

Tags: google-maps

Using Google Maps' API v3, how can I geocode a city name, and have a map returned with the outline of the result? usually this is a political entity with strict boundaries, like a city, municipality, etc.

Which [API method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) should be used?

[image]

Comment: There isn't any API (at present) that provides that data.

Comment: Hello downvoters and closers! **External APIs are strictly on-topic**.  If you have an issue with the structure of the question, let us know in the comments! If an API doesn't currently exist for a feature, that's still a valid answer. When that changes at Google, then this question can be updated with a new answer explaining how to use that new API.

Comment: I´m also looking forward for an API

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @p.campbell find any solution ? I'm also looking for this

Answer (score 6):

There isn't any API (at present) that provides that data.

[Enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=109)

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need [Tiger/Line files](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html) as referenced in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352458/tiger-lines-or-shapefiles-of-usa-states-and-cities/10821465#10821465). You can use the data to [generate polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygons). Use `Geocoder.geocode` to search for city names. Here's a promise based function that I use:

```
  function locateAddress(address) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(!address) { $q.resolve(null); return; }

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var a = address;
    if(_.isObject(a)) {
      a = (a.line1 || '') + ' ' + (a.city || '') + ' ' + (a.state || '') + ' ' +  (a.zip || '');
    }

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address' : a}, function(results, status) {
      if(status === 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
        deferred.resolve(null);
        return;
      }

      var c = results[0].geometry.location;
      deferred.resolve({latitude: c.lat(), longitude: c.lng()});
    }, function(err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to look up the boudary with a combination of different methods.

I have a simple implementation in React, using the geocoder. Basically, I strip the information to get the country name, then use reverse geocoding to get the place id for the country.

```
 const handleCountrySearch = (country: string) => {
    let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder
      .geocode({
        address: country,
      })
      .then((result: google.maps.GeocoderResponse) => {
        setCountryResult(result.results[0]);
      });
  };
```

However, you can get a better implementation according to your needs in the [Use Places APIs and Geocoding with data-driven styling for boundaries documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/dds-use-maps-places-apis)

After that, you can draw using Data Driven styling. Follow this guide from the documentation for [Data Driven Styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/overview)